# How to change HyperlinkButton background and foreground color when PointerEntered in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Here is my sample UWP code in C# and XAML
Where i created one hyperlink button in MainPage method and set the style attributes like foreground and background.

Now i want to change the background and foreground colors when PointerEntered event triggered like mouseover, in this case only font size is changing but not the colors

```
public MainPage(){
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var hLinkButton = new HyperlinkButton();

    hLinkButton.Name = "LearnMoreHyperLink";
    hLinkButton.Content = "Learn More...";

    hLinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    hLinkButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    hLinkButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
    hLinkButton.FontSize = 18.0;

    hLinkButton.PointerEntered += OnPointerEntered;
    LayoutGrid.Children.Add(hLinkButton);
}

private void OnPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e){
    var hLButton = sender as HyperlinkButton;
    hLButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    hLButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    hLButton.FontSize = 30.0;
}

// Only fontsize effecting on mouseover, background and foreground is not working
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override the style template for the HyperlinkButton to achieve this.

To do this you need to right click on your HyperLinkButton > Edit template > Edit a copy. 
Then add the relevant code to the **visual state**. In your case the visual state is "`PointerOver`".

The following code will make the foreground of the HyperLinkButton to Red and the background to white.

```
  <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
      <Storyboard>
         <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFF0000" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
   </VisualState>
```

---

**EDIT**

In c# code what you are doing is changing the Background and Foreground color of the `HyperLinkButton` which is overriding the color for the **"Normal" visual state** of the control.. While the pointer is above your control, the default control style predefined in the XAML(**for "PointerOver" state**) is showing the color that it is supposed to,so you can only see the change after the pointer is removed from your control..

Thus, overriding the xaml styling of the control is the *correct* and the best solution for PointerOver event in my opinion..

[image: Pointer over]

Please ask any further questions that you may have regarding this.. I will be happy to give a proper explanation if required.

Comment: Hi @Pratyay, thanks for your reply, But as per my requirement i should not use any XAML code, i have to use only C# code.

Comment: @Mahesh I have edited my answer and added an explanation for why your current code is not working and why it is not recommended to do such operations from C#..

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, working as expected with XAML, But still i have to write it in C# only. And i am learning C# now. Can you please share C# sample code/ links if you have

Comment: I guess we can do this in C# by defining VisualStateManager and defining its VisualStateGroups but that would unnecessarily be too complex. Unfortunately I have never tried to override them with code behind.. If you are familiar with Web technologies, just imagine if you did all the styling for HTML with Javascript.. ofcourse we can do it.. but we have CSS for a reason..Also,please post the URL if you find a good c# example for producing the same effect, i would also like to know more about it..!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way -

```
hLinkButton.PointerEntered += hLinkButton_OnPointerEntered;

private void hLinkButton_OnPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hLButton = sender as HyperlinkButton;
    hLButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    hLButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    hLButton.FontSize = 30.0;
}
```

further if you want reverse all things back, you should use Pointer **hLinkButton_PointerExited** Event

**Update**

Whats is actual problem everything looks fine with your code.

***Output with your codes***

[image: Output]

**Further** you can declare your hyper link button once like this i am done

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    HyperlinkButton hLinkButton = new HyperlinkButton();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        hLinkButton.Name = "LearnMoreHyperLink";
        hLinkButton.Content = "Learn More...";
        hLinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        hLinkButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        hLinkButton.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
        hLinkButton.FontSize = 18.0;
        hLinkButton.PointerEntered += OnPointerEntered;
        LayoutGrid.Children.Add(hLinkButton);
    }      

    private void OnPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        hLinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        hLinkButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        hLinkButton.FontSize = 30.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did same. 
What is the point you are just changing the method name. please check my question.

Comment: @Mahesh it is changing Color and font size in both method no diffrence, what is actual problem and can you set content in your hyperlink button for checking

Comment: @Shuham Sahu, I updated the code, 1. Name 2. Content 3. Font Weight 4. Font Size. And Target version: Win 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393), Min Build is 10586.

Comment: Your screenshot image also showing same results like on mouse over the background and foreground colors are not changing as we expected. That is showing default colors. As i mentioned only Font Size will change.

Comment: Okay ! are you want that gray color appear on mouse over on hyperlink button should also be red ? is this real question , it is because it is default property of hyperlink button in xaml style you can edit it using blend and for c# wait.. let me test it with my codes....

Comment: Yes exactly, once mouse out it should be in initial state (background color, foreground color)

Comment: @Mahesh for that purpose you can use     hLinkButton_PointerExited    event

Comment: InitialState: (Border, Background, Foreground) = (Black, Red, White)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159388/discussion-between-mahesh-and-shubham-sahu).